# algorithm2e - can't get ends to line up in for loop

Tags: algorithm2e, code, pseudocode

This is my code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Computes Flux in x and y direction}
\KwIn{arrays flux\_x and flux\_y of length $x \times y$}
\SetKwArray{fluxx}{flux_x}
\SetKwArray{fluxy}{flux_y}
\SetKwArray{q}{q}
\For{$i \gets 0$ \textbf{to} $x$} {
    \For{$j \gets 0$ \textbf{to} $y$} {
        $index \gets getIndex(i,j)$
        \\If{ $j \neq 0$}{
            \fluxx{index} = $$\frac{1}{2} \times (\q{index} + \q{index-1}) - ((\frac{\alpha}{2}) \times (\q{index} - \q{index-1}))$$
        }
        \\If{ $i \neq 0$}{
            \fluxy{index} = $$\frac{1}{2} \times (\q{index} + \q{index-x}) - ((\frac{\alpha}{2}) \times (\q{index} - \q{index-x}))$$
        }  
    }
}
\end{algorithm}
```

The end statements that occur at the end of a for loop will not line up correctly. The end statement for the innermost loop  is next to the end of the final if's body, and then the end for the outermost loop is underneath this.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are extra `\\`s not needed, plus I'm not sure of the definition of `\fluxx{index}` and `\fluxy{index}` and added `$$` to it.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Computes Flux in x and y direction}
\KwIn{arrays $flux\_x$ and $flux\_y$ of length $x \times y$}
\SetKwArray{fluxx}{$flux_x$}
\SetKwArray{fluxy}{$flux_y$}
\SetKwArray{q}{q}
\For{$i \gets 0$  \KwTo $x$} {%
    \For{$j \gets 0$  \KwTo $y$} {%
        $index \gets getIndex(i,j)$\\
        \If{$j \neq 0$}{%
            $\fluxx{index}= \frac{1}{2} \times (\q{index} + \q{index-1}) - ((\frac{\alpha}{2}) \times (\q{index} - \q{index-1}))$
        }
        \If{$i \neq 0$}{%
            $\fluxy{index} = \frac{1}{2} \times (\q{index} + \q{index-x}) - ((\frac{\alpha}{2}) \times (\q{index} - \q{index-x}))$
        } 
    }
}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]